# Blank form in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am creating a Microsoft Access form and I have to use multiple tables to create the form. I'm currently using a query to add all of the fields to the form, but the form is showing up blank everywhere except in design view and if I move a field into the header it then appears. How do I make the whole form visible without using subforms?

Comment: Have you tried using the wizard to create a form bounded to your query?

Comment: I used the query wizard to create a query with each field from the tables and then used form wizard to create a form with that query and its still blank everywhere except in the header

Comment: Can you poste some images of the query and the form?